# How do you make a batch file that opens an exe but also "clicks" the run button in that exe?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can get the batch file to open it, but I don't know how to get it to execute the "Run Test" button. Whats the command line for this?

Comment: Batch files can't click buttons.

Comment: more, batch files cannot interact withh gui applications.

Comment: This is one of the only times I'll recommend powershell for a question marked with the [batch-file] tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer, I think tabs are best without being able to see what your windows with the button looks like. {Tab 6} here just needs to be changed. When you open the EXE with the "Run Test" button, just hit tab until you are focused on the "Run Test" button. Count the number of times you hit tab, then change the "6" in my code to that number.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

start notepad
timeout /t 3

%SendKeys% ("{tab 6}{enter}")

goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```